# If developed countries go through an economic depression, what happens to developing & underdeveloped countries?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, gdp, behavioral-macroeconomics, great-depression

With the historical inflation data throughout 2022 from the US & England, also with the hawkish view from the Federal Reserve, Bank of England & other analysts of the possibility of an incoming depression, it makes me wonder how it will affect countries of different leagues if it were to happen.

The reasoning behind this is because the inflation around South East Asia for instance is within the normal range & some have increasing GDP.

For example, I was wondering if developed countries' cost of living is too high, will it push the companies to open businesses in developing countries & indirectly help their economy, or will the depression in their country stop them?

Would appreciate a simplified broader answer to the main question. Thanks!